# c# How to use linq to get xml string by filtering some data?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to get xml string by filtering data. For example, I need to filter some students whose sex is female.

I need to use linq to xml to get xml string.
The following is my initial xml code and expected xml string.

Initial xml code:

```
 <? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <School>
    <Student>
          <Name>Test1</Name>
          <Birthday>1997-02-23</Birthday>
          <Id>1001</Id>
          <Sex>male</Sex>
          <ClassId>01</ClassId>
          <Scorevalue>Net Revenue</Scorevalue>
    </Student>
    <Student>
          <Name>Test1</Name>
          <Birthday>1998-02-21</Birthday>
          <Id>1002</Id>
          <Sex>female</Sex>
          <ClassId>02</ClassId>
          <Scorevalue>Net Revenue</Scorevalue>
    </Student>
    <Student>
          <Name>Test1</Name>
          <Birthday>1997-02-24</Birthday>
          <Id>1004</Id>
          <Sex>male</Sex>
          <ClassId>03</ClassId>
          <Scorevalue></Scorevalue>
    </Student>
    </School>
```

Expected xml string:

```
<School>
  <Student>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Birthday>1998-02-21</Birthday>
    <Id>1002</Id>
    <Sex>female</Sex>
    <ClassId>02</ClassId>
    <Scorevalue>Net Revenue</Scorevalue>
  </Student>
</School>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the xml string like this,

```
string path = "D:\\test.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
doc.Descendants("Student").Where(x =>x.Element("Sex").Value=="male").Remove();
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        foreach(var x in doc.Descendants("Student").Where(x => x.Element("Sex").Value == "female"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        }
```